# Transparent background of PNG saves as black

Tags: php

I recently followed [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/) tutorial, but the thing is when I save a PNG it has a solid black background?.. I am rather new to php.. how do I save it with a transparent background?

Here's the php class:

```
# include("classes/resize_class.php");
# $resizeObj = new resize('images/cars/large/input.jpg');
# $resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 0);
# $resizeObj -> saveImage('images/cars/large/output.jpg', 100);

Class resize {
    // *** Class variables
    private $image;
    private $width;
    private $height;
    private $imageResized;

    function __construct($fileName) {
        // *** Open up the file
        $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

        // *** Get width and height
        $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
        $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function openImage($file)
    {
        // *** Get extension
        $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

        switch($extension)
        {
            case '.jpg':
            case '.jpeg':
                $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                break;
            case '.gif':
                $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                break;
            case '.png':
                $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                break;
            default:
                $img = false;
                break;
        }
        return $img;
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
    {
        // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
        $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

        $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];

        // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
        $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);

        // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
        if ($option == 'crop') {
            $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option){

        switch ($option)
        {
            case 'exact':
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                break;
            case 'portrait':
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                break;
            case 'landscape':
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                break;
            case 'auto':
                $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                break;
            case 'crop':
                $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                break;
        }
        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
    {
        $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
        $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
        return $newWidth;
    }

    private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
    {
        $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
        $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
        return $newHeight;
    }

    private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
    {
        if ($this->height < $this->width)
        // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
        {
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
        }
        elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
        // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
        {
            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
        }
        else
        // *** Image to be resized is a square
        {
            if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            } else {
                // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            }
        }
        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
    {
        $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
        $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;
        if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
            $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
        } else {
            $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
        }

        $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
        $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
    {
        // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
        $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
        $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

        $crop = $this->imageResized;
        //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

        // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
        $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
    {
        // *** Get extension
        $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
        $extension = strtolower($extension);

        switch($extension)
        {
            case '.jpg':
            case '.jpeg':
                if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                    imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                }
                break;
            case '.gif':
                if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                    imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                }
                break;
            case '.png':
                // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);
                // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                    imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                }
                break;
            // ... etc
            default:
                // *** No extension - No save.
                break;
        }

        imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
    }
}

?>
```

a lot of code i know.. but i wouldn't know which parts are vital..apologies...

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the resizeImage function to:

```
    public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto"){
        // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
        $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];

        // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
        $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);

        // *** EDIT BY JDUB - add transparent background, for png images
        //2. Create an alpha-transparent color and fill the image with it */
        imagealphablending($this->imageResized, false);
        imagesavealpha($this->imageResized, true);
        $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->imageResized, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($this->imageResized, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $bg);
        imagecolortransparent($this->imageResized, $bg);
        // *** END EDIT BY JDUB

        imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);

        // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
        if ($option == 'crop') {
        $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }
    }
```

this saves the transparency.

Answer (score 1):

I was change function resizeImage and it was not working. Now I found the problem, if you use $option = 'crop', you must change the function crop too.

Here it is:

```
      private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
        {
            // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
            $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
            $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

            $crop = $this->imageResized;
            //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);


            // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);

            if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                imagealphablending($this->imageResized, false);
                imagesavealpha($this->imageResized, true);
                $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->imageResized, 255, 255, 255, 127);
                imagefilledrectangle($this->imageResized, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $bg);

            }

            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find your answer here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php

Comment: there are answers.. but implementation.. <- entirely different story